# super basic regex

Tags: regex

I'm using these:

```
.*cq.*
.*conquest.*
```

The first one matches any word/phrase/sentence/etc. with the letters 'cq' in it. The second one does the same thing but for the word 'conquest'. Are these regex correct?

Also, how do I combine these two regex so I don't have two entries?

Thank you and I'm sorry for the super noob questions! :o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "combining" you mean matching every entry that contains either one of those :

```
.*(cq|conquest).*
```

Answer (score 2):

Combining is simple

```
(cq|conquest)
```

will match these 1 of 2 occurences

Comment: Prefer this to the accepted answer if the regex is being used for testing whether the string conforms. Assuming that's the case, the .* at the beginning and end are superfluous as there's no need to grab everything (which could be very inefficient if it were a long input string).

Answer (score 0):

Could even use

```
c(q|onquest)
```

should do the trick